# c++ fstream read() function not working

Tags: c++

Why my following code fails to read single integer from file?
It displays "fail() reading" followed by "0".

On linux ubuntu gcc compiler.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream fout2("int_data",ios::binary|ios::out);
    int a = 2;
    fout2.write((char*)&a,sizeof(a));
    int b=0;
    ifstream fin2("int_data",ios::binary|ios::in);
    fin2.read((char*)&b,sizeof(b));
    if(fin2.fail())
        cout << "fail() reading" << endl;
    cout << b << endl;
}
```

Comment: You're not flushing after the write (or verifying that it worked).

Answer (score 1):

This could fail for a couple reasons:

1. Your OS may be protecting you from opening a file that is currently opened for writing
2. You may not have flushed your data to the file

You can solve both of these by using [`close`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/close) before you construct `fin2`:

```
ofstream fout2("int_data", ios::binary);
const int a = 2;

fout2.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&a), sizeof(a));
fout2.close();

int b = 0;
ifstream fin2("int_data", ios::binary);

if(!fin2.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&b), sizeof(b))) {
    cout << "fail() reading" << endl;
}
cout << b << endl;;
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1d5e4a8f347fc93)